# What is the proper way to test if a capturing group captured something in g_regex_split_simple

Tags: c, regex, glib

When using glib's g_regex_split_simple, what is the best way check if a capture group actually captured anything?

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {    
        char *teststring = "<initiator>{address == 10.20.30.40, port == 5060, transport == UDP}</initiator>";

        char **addressMatches = g_regex_split_simple("address\\s*=*\\s*(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3})", teststring, 0, 0);

        // What is the proper way to test here that there was a match found?
        // This sort of works sometimes, but can result in segfault on some platforms if a match is not found
        if (addressMatches[2]) {
                printf("IP: %s\n", addressMatches[1]);
        }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a split function and not a match function?

Comment: Does the match function only return a boolean?  Is it possible to get capture groups out of the match functions?

Comment: The best documentation I could find on the match function is here: https://lzone.de/examples/Glib%20GRegex.  But it looks a lot more complicated than the split function in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {    
        char *teststring = "<initiator>{address == 10.20.30.40, port == 5060, transport == UDP}</initiator>";

        char **addressMatches = g_regex_split_simple("address\\s*=*\\s*(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3})", teststring, 0, 0);

       //The trailing text will be at index 2 if there was a match
       //Otherwise index 2 will be a null pointer
       //The captured text will be at index 1 if there was a match
       if (addressMatches[1] != NULL && addressMatches[2] != NULL) {
                printf("IP: %s\n", addressMatches[1]);
       }
}
```